# Regular Expression : Splitting a string of list of multivalues

Tags: regex, string, list, split

My goal is splitting this string with regular expression:

```
AA(1.2,1.3)+,BB(125)-,CC(A,B,C)-,DD(QWE)+
```

in a list of:

- AA(1.2,1.3)+
- BB(125)-
- CC(A,B,C)-
- DD(QWE)+

Regards.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Why not use String.split(",")?

Comment: you can't use `String.split(",")` because it would split `AA(1.2,1.3)+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex works with your sample string:

```
,(?![^(]+\))
```

This splits on comma, but uses a negative lookahead to assert that the next bracket character is not a right bracket. It will still split even if there are no following brackets.

Here's some java code demonstrating it working with your sample plus some general input showing its robustness:

```
String input = "AA(1.2,1.3)+,BB(125)-,FOO,CC(A,B,C)-,DD(QWE)+,BAR";
String[] split = input.split(",(?![^(]+\\))");
for (String s : split) System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
AA(1.2,1.3)+
BB(125)-
FOO
CC(A,B,C)-
DD(QWE)+
BAR
```

Comment: new Scanner("AA(1.2,1.3)+,BB(125)-,CC(A,B,C)-,DD(QWE)+").useDelimiter(",(?![^(]+\\))");

Comment: This pattern is perfect for the tokenization with Scanner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you are working with, but this makes it in `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[A-Z]*([A-Z0-9.,]*)[^,]*' file
AA(1.2,1.3)+
BB(125)-
CC(A,B,C)-
DD(QWE)+
```

#### Explanation

```
[A-Z]*([A-Z0-9.,]*)[^,]*
^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^
  |   ^       |   ^   |
  |   |       |   |   everything but a comma
  |   ( char  |   ) char
  |          A-Z 0-9 . or , chars
list of chars from A to Z
```

Comment: My regards! It is Java, but regexs abstract the problem. I have a basic knowledge about regex. With thier one can rule the entire world! :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad to read it was useful to you :) And in fact yes, I agree, with regex you can rule the world!!

Comment: And grep can break every system! It should must be a super-user command only! B-)